# JAXB generating wrong Namespace

Tags: jaxb

I have a xsd (lets name it as afb) which imports another xsd (lets name it as kts). And I refer to an element of kts.xsd in afb.xsd along with correct namespaces.

But when I generate the classes using JAXB, the namespace for refered element is wrong.

I mean, the referred element should have kts namespace where as it is having afb namespace.

Because of which validating my XML against this xsd is failing also not able to bind the xml data into the java models.

EX:
afb.xsd :

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.boschkts.com" schemaLocation="kts.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="vehicle">

<xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="vType"/>
          <xs:element name="RESULTS" type="kts:RESULTS" >
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

kts:xsd :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.boschkts.com" 
targetNamespace="http://www.boschkts.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:complexType name="RESULTS">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SUMMARY" type="SUMMARY" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Vehicle.java :

```
public class Vehicle {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.boschafb.com", required = true)
    protected String vType;
    @XmlElement(name = "RESULTS", namespace = "http://www.boschafb.com", required = true)
    protected Results results;

}
```

If I observe the Vehicle.java, the namespace of results property should have been "http://www.bosch**kts**.com" instead of "http://www.boschafb.com"

If I change the namespace manually then binding the data from xml to java models works.
But still validating against the xsd fails with the error :

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'kts:RESULTS'. One of '{"http://www.boschafb.com":RESULTS}' is expected.

Can anybody point what I might be missing in the xsd? or is it the way jaxb generates and I have to modify the classes manually?

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuing your `abf.xsd` starts with

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.boschafb.com"
           targetNamespace="http://www.boschafb.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

With `elementFormDefault` set to `qualified`, all element declarations, even nested ones, belong to the specified target namespace. Note that this applies only to elements, a referenced type does not affect the namespace of the element referencing it.

A solution would be to define an element instead of a type in 'kts.xsd' and referencing this element in your first schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.boschkts.com" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.boschkts.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="RESULTS">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SUMMARY" type="SUMMARY" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.boschafb.com"
           targetNamespace="http://www.boschafb.com" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:kts="http://www.boschkts.com">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.boschkts.com" schemaLocation="kts.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="vehicle">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="vType"/>
                <xs:element ref="kts:RESULT"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I don't know if this solved the OP's problem, but it worked for me - I had a child element from an imported schema that was taking the parent namespace when it should have retained the imported namespace.  Changing from `<element type='childNS:whateverType' />` to `<element ref='childNS:whateverElement' />` worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using an include instead of an import like so:

`<xs:include schemaLocation="kts.xsd"/>` instead of `<xs:import namespace="http://www.boschkts.com" schemaLocation="kts.xsd"/>`

This style causes far less problems with intra-namespace includes.